# How to resolve the $ conflict between jQuery and mooTools?

Tags: jquery, mootools

Okay, I have been working for quite some time on a website for a friend.. My coding skills are .. questionable, and I've been having quite a few problems.

Currently the jQuery on my site simply stopped working, I could not find the reason, and I have done everything I could to try to get it to work. ( I have followed countless guides all over the internet, for troubleshooting etc. and I still cannot get it to work)

Then after looking closely at the errors, using the browser console I've found out that mootools and jQuery are conflicting between `$`.

I've been trying to use `jQuery.noConflict()` but I can't seem to figure out how to use it.

Could anyone help me?

Sincerely yours, Malmoc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After making the call to [`jQuery.noConflict()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) you just need to refer to the jQuery object as `jQuery` instead of `$`. Your code would need to be updated to reflect this:

```
$(document).ready();
```

Would become

```
$.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready();
```

Answer (score 2):

Once you've called `$.noConflict()`, you would proceed to use `jQuery` instead. If you want to continue using `$`, you can do so by using a closure:

```
// Free-up $
$.noConflict();
// Use jQuery as '$' safely
(function($){
    // Fire on ready
    $(function(){
        alert( "Page loaded" );
    });
})(jQuery);
```

This prevents any outside code from tampering with the `$` within the closure.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery.noConflict() restores the value of $ to whatever it was before.

This means you're going to have to use `jQuery` to refer to jQuery from then on.

A neat way to keep using jQuery as $ is to do something like this:

```
(function ($) {
    // $ is actually jQuery here
    $(document).ready(function () {

    })
}(jQuery))
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would be to wrap your jQuery code like so:

```
(function($)
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#myelementID').fadeIn(399);

        //do other jQuery stuff ....
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

$ = jQuery

jQuery = $

Your experiencing collision of your $,

```
A. Drop Mootools or Jquery
B. Use jQuery('selector') instead of $()
C. Reference the $ to something else, buckWildProgramming = $
```

Hope that helps.